# Strings - Data Type

Tags: c

I have learned how to handle all data types except, strings. So, can anyone help me with the strings?

Comment: *Is it something like that?* is a bit vague. What's your specific question?

Comment: As a famous captain once said, There are *four* chars!

Comment: This is a great guide that covers the concept http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html

Comment: Oh, yes. I know that website tutorial. It is written by Alex Allain.

Comment: Can you please up vote my answer if you agree, thanks

Comment: It is great to know that you are just 6th standard student and learning programming. Its good that you joined SO and it will help you a lot through out this journey. Do not get demotivated by the downvotes to your answer and harsh comments, just ignore them. First, I would suggest you to follow a simple book like [C Programming Absolute Beginner's Guide](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Absolute-Beginners-Guide-Edition/dp/0789751984/ref=pd_sim_14_7?ie=UTF8&refRID=1XZ1W4XEFQ870GCJTBCA). Then, next time you come here  to ask something first search it on google. If you find then good otherwise..

Comment: ...ask on SO. People here are eager to help kids like you. Enjoy programming. :)

Comment: @haccks, you are the only user who have been so generous to me. Thank you; at first, I felt bad out here; but, your cheerful comments have made me very happy. And, once again, my heartiest thankfulness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this declaration

```
char surnm[4] = {'P', 'i', 'n', 'e', '\0'};
```

there are 5 initializers but only 4 elements in array `surnm`. So the array will not contain a string because it did not included the terminating zero. You should write either

```
char surnm[5] = {'P', 'i', 'n', 'e', '\0'};
```

or

```
char surnm[] = {'P', 'i', 'n', 'e', '\0'};
```

or

```
char surnm[5] = { "Pine" };
```

or

```
char surnm[5] = "Pine";
```

or

```
char surnm[] = { "Pine" };
```

or

```
char surnm[] = "Pine";
```

Comment: No, absolutely, not. It is, in fact, a great answer. I liked all of my answers but, I had to choose one.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a string as an array of chars or a pointer to a char, strings terminate with a null (0 byte)

Examples:

```
char c[]="abcd";  
char c1[5]="abcd"; 
char c2[]={'a','b','c','d','\0'}; 
char c3[5]={'a','b','c','d','\0'};
char *c4="abcd";
```

Comment: It is interesting who down-voted your answer.

Comment: Can you up vote if you agree, thanks

Comment: Thanks Vlad, appreciated :-)

Comment: Maybe the fact that `*c4` is a readonly string, whereas the rest are not could serve as a reason for down-voting (wasn't me)

Comment: Still a valid case for a string be it read only, the question is to explain string usage in C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

### String: array of characters

1. string: array of characters terminated by null character `'\0'`. Declaration: `char S[array_size];`
2. string in/output:

   `scanf("%s",S);`  `printf("%s",S);`
3. `string.h` :collection of functions for string manipulation
4. no standard operators for string assignment and comparisons!
   (remember: strings are arrays!)

A sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 80

int main() {

  /* strings are array of characters 
   * terminated by the NULL character
   * which is different from '0' */

  char S[MAX_STRING_LEN];
  int l, i;

  S[0] = 'a';
  S[1] = 'b';
  S[2] = 'c';
  S[3] = 'd';
  S[4] = 'e';
  S[5] = 'g';
  S[6] = '0';
  S[7] = 0;

  l = strlen(S);

  printf("S:\t%s\n",S);
  printf("length:\t%d\n",l);

  /* print characters in S */

  printf("forward\n");
  for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) 
    printf("A[%d] = %c\n",i,S[i]);

  /* print characters in S backwards */

  printf("\nbackward\n");
  for (i = l-1; i >= 0; --i) 
    printf("A[%d] = %c\n",i,S[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is good to explain strings to a 6th standard girl. +1